# @ManyToMany no entries in linking table

Tags: jsf, jpa, many-to-many, entity, jpa-2.0

Perhaps someone here can give me a tip where the error could be situated (JSF 2.2, Glassfish 4.0):

- I have two entities with a manytomany relation (see example)
- When I deploy my project in glassfish all tables (also the linking table) are generated correctly (create-tables enabled in persistence.xml): TAGUSERWISH, TAGUSERWISH_WISH (linking table), WISH
- When I execute a persist (see example) entity "wish" and "tagUserWish" is persisted correctly, but nothing is written into the linking table when I look directly into the mysql table. But when I read "wish" out with JPA, the `List<TagUserWish>` is filled
- As soon as a new session starts (redeploy) `List<TagUserWish>` is also empty when read out with JPA

Owner entity:

```
@Entity
public class Wish implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String subject;
    private String abstractT;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "wishes", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
    private List<TagUserWish> tags = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addTag(TagUserWish tag){
        tags.add(tag);
    }

    public void setTags(List<TagUserWish> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }       

    public void removeTag(TagUserWish tag){
        tags.remove(tag);
    }

    public List<TagUserWish> getTags(){
        return tags;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getAbstractT() {
        return abstractT;
    }

    public void setAbstractT(String abstractT) {
        this.abstractT = abstractT;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Wish)) {
            return false;
        }
        Wish other = (Wish) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "eu.citato.main.model.Wish[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Entity 2:

```
@Entity
public class TagUserWish implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;        
    private String name;

    public TagUserWish() {
    }          

    public TagUserWish(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }          

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Wish> wishes = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addWish(Wish wish){
        wishes.add(wish);
    }

    public void setWishes(List<Wish> wishes) {
        this.wishes = wishes;
    }       

    public void removeWish(Wish tag){
        wishes.remove(tag);
    }

    public List<Wish> getWishes(){
        return wishes;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof TagUserWish)) {
            return false;
        }
        TagUserWish other = (TagUserWish) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "eu.citato.main.model.Tag[ id=" + id + ", name="+name+" ]";
    }     
}
```

How I persist it:

```
@javax.inject.Named 
@SessionScoped
public class WishPM implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private WishService wls;

    public void commitEditWish(){        
        List<TagUserWish> selTags = new ArrayList<>();
        selTags.add(new TagUserWish("Tag1"));
        selTags.add(new TagUserWish("Tag2"));
        currentWish = new Wish();
        currentWish.setSubject("wishSubject");
        currentWish.setAbstractT("wishAbstract");
        currentWish.setTags(selTags);
        wls.createWish(currentWish);
    }
}
```

And the wish Service:

```
@Stateless
public class WishService implements Serializable{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WishlistPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void createWish(Wish entity){
        em.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships are persisted based to the owner side of relationship. Owner of the bidirectional relationship is one that is value of `mappedBy` in inverse side. In following case owner of the relationship is `wishes` field in `TagUserWish` entity

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "wishes", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
private List<TagUserWish> tags = new LinkedList<>();
```

Because instance of `TagUserWish` do have empty `wishes` collection, relationship is not persisted. Problem can be solved by adding related Wish to the instance of `TagUserWish`, for example as follows:

```
...
TagUserWish tuw1 = new TagUserWish("Tag1")
TagUserWish tuw2 = new TagUserWish("Tag2")

selTags.add(tuw1);
selTags.add(tuw2);

currentWish = new Wish();
tuw1.addWish(currentWish); //setting to owner side of relationship
tuw2.addWish(currentWish); //setting to owner side of relationship
...
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly where the error was situated. But perhaps I can ask one more question for better understanding: Subsequently I tried to mark entity `TagUserWish` with `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")` and entity `Wish` with `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )` because this way the persisting would be less code, like in my example. But this didn't work. `WISH_TAGUSERWISH` was created but nothing inserted by persisting. Shouldn't this work?